# Display Data from fetch api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, fetch-api

Hi i want to fetch data from avascan api and display it in html, but i am not able to do this. I have tried fetch api, json and ajax ways but none worked for me. Any suggestions? This is my html https://avascan.info/api/v1/home/statistics

```js
const api_url = 'https://avascan.info/api/v1/home/statistics';


async function getAVA() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const {
    blockchains,
    validators
  } = data;
  document.getElementById('lat').textContent = blockchains.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('lon').textContent = validators.toFixed(2);
}

getAVA();

setInterval(getAVA, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>What the stats?</h1>

<p>
  blockchains: <span id="lat"></span>°<br /> validators: <span id="lon"></span>°
</p>

<div id="issMap"></div>
```

Comment: You are probably being hit by a CORS error. is your javascript code on the same domain as the API (https://avascan.info/api/v1/home/statistics)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a CORS protection error, as mentioned before.

However it seems you need to use a GraphQL API: https://graphql.avascan.info/

Look at this quick example:

```
      async function getAVA() {

        fetch('https://graphql.avascan.info', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
            query: `
            query {
                stats {
                    priceAvaxUsd,
                    connectedNodes
                }
            }`
            }),
            })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((result) => console.log(result));
      }

      getAVA();
```

Comment: I also need total no. Of validators and blockchains to display them in html, seems like it cannot retrive them, btw how do I show this console. Log data in html?

Comment: It seems you will need to wait to accomplish what you need. The GraphQL API is deprecated and the new one is not yet available. https://docs.avascan.info/quickstart-graphql#api-version-0-3

Comment: to show the data in html instead of console.log, you would need to move these commands `document.getElementById('lat').textContent = result.data.stats.connectedNodes.toFixed(2);`  inside the last `then`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is a CORS protection and you may need certain requirements to fetch this dat such an **api key**, or update configuration your options in the fetch method

Here is a  [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to help